# Сравнить два сложных списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пробовал решить задачу в python.

Есть два списка:

```py
a = "с1,c2,c3,c8-c11"
b = "с1,c3,c2,c10-c13"

result=list(set(a) - set(b))
print(result)
```

Проблема в том, что это не работает, когда в списке есть диапазоны(c10-c13).

Нужно разбить диапазон с8-с11 на с8,c9,c10,c11 и с10-с13 соответственно, а потом полностью сравнить списки и вывести на экран их отличия.

Comment: Что такое (с1,c2,c3,c8-c11) ? Вы же понимаете, что если люди не могут понять ваш вопрос, то они не могут и помочь вам?

Comment: Внес исправления

Comment: `Нужно разбить диапазон с8-с11 на с8,c9,c10,c11 и с10-с13 соответственно, а потом полностью сравнить списки и вывести на экран их отличия` так вы уже знаете, что вам делать.

Comment: я новичек и не знаю синтаксиса для решения этой задачи...

Comment: @Александр, разбиваете строку по `,`, перебирая элементы проверяйте те, у которых есть `-` -- из нужно разбить на две части, найти число и в цикле перебрать от меньшего к большему, заполняя значениями `"c" + str(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите функция для разбора, например:

```
def parse_list(text: str) -> list:
    # с1,c2,c3,c8-c11 -> ['с1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11']
    items = []

    for x in text.split(','):
        if '-' in x:
            a, b = x.split('-')
            a, b = int(a[1:]), int(b[1:])
            items += ['c' + str(i) for i in range(a, b + 1)]

        else:
            items.append(x)

    return items
```

С помощью функции получите список, а дальше останется вывести их отличия:

```
a = "с1,c2,c3,c8-c11"
b = "с1,c3,c2,c10-c13"

a_items = parse_list(a)
print(a_items)  # ['с1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11']

b_items = parse_list(b)
print(b_items)  # ['с1', 'c3', 'c2', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13']

result = list(set(a_items) - set(b_items))
print(result)  # ['c8', 'c9']

result = list(set(b_items) - set(a_items))
print(result)  # ['c13', 'c12']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!